# Dashed short circuits in CircuiTikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I have a circuit in CircuiTikz in which I am trying to add a dashed short circuit. I know about the `\draw[dashed]`, but this gives me dashed lines also in the endpoints.[image: Circuit with dashed lines]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw           (0,0)       node[op amp] (opAmp) {};

        \draw           (opAmp.-)   to[short,-] ++(-0.5,0) coordinate (J5);

        \draw[dashed]   (J5)        to[short,*-o] ++(0,2)
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to not have the endpoints dashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to not use the `circ` and `ocirc` shapes defined by `circuitikz` but to define styles with the same names so that TikZ does not choose the shapes.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\tikzset{
  circ/.style={
    shape=circle,
    color/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color},
    draw, fill, solid, inner sep=+0pt,
    minimum size=2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
  },
  ocirc/.style={circ, fill=white}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw           (0,0)       node[op amp] (opAmp) {};
  \draw           (opAmp.-)   to[short,-] ++(-0.5,0) coordinate (J5);
  \draw[dashed]   (J5)        to[short,*-o] ++(0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Though, if you look closer, that line actually is put together by two lines with a null-node in the middle (the `shortshape`). This is the reason the dashing is not consistent. It becomes very noticeable if you do

```
  \draw[dashed] (J5) to[short,*-o] ++(0,1);
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Now preferred answer! Thanks!

Comment: with recent `circuitikz` it doesn't work anymore. error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
                                                  
l.21 ...ashed]   (J5)        to[short,*-o] ++(0,2)
                                                  ;`

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw           (0,0)       node[op amp] (opAmp) {};

        \draw           (opAmp.-)   to[short,-] ++(-0.5,0) coordinate (J5);

       \draw [dashed] (J5)to[short,-] ++(0,2)coordinate (J6);
       \filldraw(J5)circle(2pt);
       \filldraw[fill=white](J6)circle(2pt);

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is perfect, even though a little bit tedious in the effective application given the number of those elements I have to add, but that is CircuiTikz and Tikz...